# Understand $controller in Jasmine test

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I'm relative new to Jasmine. I read a tutorial that has the below code:

```
angular.module('moduleX', []).controller('HomeCtrl',function($scope) {
  $scope.showData = function(data) {
    $scope.$broadcast('showData', data);
  };
});
```

Here is the test:

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
   scope = $rootScope.$new();
   $controller('HomeCtrl', {
      $scope: scope
   });
   spyOn(scope, '$broadcast');
}));

it('should call $broadcast', function() {
    scope.showData();
    expect(scope.$broadcast).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

My question is how everything works? if scope = $rootScope.$new(); then I assume scope becomes a brand new empty scope and there's no showData method on scope, so how can scope.showData() work? I think $controller only helps instantiating a new HomeCtrl but it is not assigned to any variable (I expect to see something like `var homeCtrl = $controller('HomeCtrl', {$scope: scope});`) I'm not sure if it has anything to do with the scope variable in this case?

---

**Some notes:** I make some console.log to see the scope variable:

```
  scope = $rootScope.$new();
  console.log("scope before",scope)
  $controller('HomeCtrl', {
    $scope: scope
  });
  console.log("scope after",scope)
```

I can see that now there is showData in "scope after", so $controller has modified the original scope variable along the way. I'm not sure why and think it's kind of unintuitive that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $controller service is responsible for instantiating controllers.
>   https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$controller

In first code example you create controller, which need $scope as dependency and create function showData as $scope property.

In beforeEach new empty scope is created and next $controller service is called   - thats mean 
*create me 'HomeCtrl' instance and $scope parameter is passed by scope (new empty scope created on previous line)*

Within the controller instantiation controller constructor is called , which adds method showData as $scope property.

By the way, better solution is using controllerAs syntax, because then controller is standard JS constructor function with method on this instead of $scope (this.showData for example)